# disable side menu swipe event while usIng horizontal slider- ionic

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic Side Menu to make navigation drawer . One my views uses horizontal image slider . I realized that horizontal drag action of side menu is disturbing image slider . It is working perfect on browsers but didnt work when run natively in ipad.

**SIDE MENU**

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content> 

    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
  <ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-positive">
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button" ng-click="doSomething()">Welcome,Sumit</button>
  </div>
  <h1 class="title"><img class="title-image" src="http://graph.facebook.com/11545902/picture" width="50" height="50" /></h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
       <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/home">
          Home
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close ng-click="login()">
            Login
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/cakes">
          Cake
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/gifts">
          Gifts
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/accessories">
          Accessories
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

**HORIZONTAL SCROLLER**

```
<ion-view view-title="Dashboard">

    <ion-content ng-controller="HomeCtrl" >
         <div class="card">
            <div class="item item-divider">
                Current Deal
            </div>
            <div class="item item-text-wrap">

            <hscroller>
                <hcard  index="1" desc="item1" image="avatar.png"></hcard>
                <hcard  index="2" desc="item2" image="avatar.png"></hcard>
                <hcard  index="3" desc="item3" image="avatar.png"></hcard>
                <hcard  index="4" desc="item4" image="avatar.png"></hcard>
                <hcard  index="5" desc="item5" image="avatar.png"></hcard>
                <hcard  index="6" desc="item6" image="avatar.png"></hcard>
                <hcard  index="7" desc="item7" image="avatar.png"></hcard>
                <hcard  index="8" desc="item8" image="avatar.png"></hcard>
                <hcard  index="9" desc="item9" image="avatar.png"></hcard>
                <hcard  index="10" desc="item10" image="avatar.png"></hcard>


            </hscroller>  
            </div>


        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="item item-divider">
                Urgent Cakes for Today with slider
            </div>
            <div class="item item-text-wrap">
            <hscroller>
                <hcard  index="1" desc="item1" image="avatar.png"></hcard>
                <hcard  index="2" desc="item2" image="avatar.png"></hcard>
                <hcard  index="3" desc="item3" image="avatar.png"></hcard>
                <hcard  index="4" desc="item4" image="avatar.png"></hcard>
                <hcard  index="5" desc="item5" image="avatar.png"></hcard>
                <hcard  index="6" desc="item6" image="avatar.png"></hcard>
                <hcard  index="7" desc="item7" image="avatar.png"></hcard>
                <hcard  index="8" desc="item8" image="avatar.png"></hcard>
                <hcard  index="9" desc="item9" image="avatar.png"></hcard>
                <hcard  index="10" desc="item10" image="avatar.png"></hcard>


            </hscroller>    
            </div>


        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="item item-divider">
                categories
            </div>
            <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                <div class="list">


  <a class="item item-icon-left item-icon-right" href="#">
    <i class="icon ion-bag"></i>
    Love Cake
    <i class="icon icon ion-arrow-right-c"></i>
  </a>

<a class="item item-icon-left item-icon-right" href="#">
    <i class="icon ion-bag"></i>
    Wedding Cake
    <i class="icon icon ion-arrow-right-c"></i>
  </a>

  <a class="item item-icon-left item-icon-right" href="#">
    <i class="icon ion-bag"></i>
    Sporty Cake
    <i class="icon icon ion-arrow-right-c"></i>
  </a>
  <a class="item item-icon-left item-icon-right" href="#">
    <i class="icon ion-bag"></i>
    See all
    <i class="icon icon ion-arrow-right-c"></i>
  </a>


</div>
            </div>


        </div>



    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `side-menu-content drag-content="false"` to side-menu.
working codepen [link](http://codepen.io/NewbieDev/pen/rxzxYL)

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <title>Tabs Example</title>

    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.14/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.14/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>


    <ion-side-menus >

        <ion-side-menu-content ng-controller="NavCtrl" side-menu-content drag-content="false">
          <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
            <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c">
            </ion-nav-back-button>

            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
              <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" ng-click="showMenu()">
              </button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>

            <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
              <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-ios7-gear" ng-click="showRightMenu()">
              </button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
          </ion-nav-bar>
          <ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-side-menu-content> 

        <ion-side-menu side="left">
          <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-assertive">
            <h1 class="title">Left Menu</h1>
          </ion-header-bar>
          <ion-content has-header="true">
            <ul class="list">
              <li>
                <a class="item" menu-close nav-clear href="#/tab/home">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a class="item" menu-close href="#/tab/facts">Facts</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a class="item" menu-close href="#/tab/facts2">More Facts</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu>

        <ion-side-menu side="right">
          <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-dark">
            <h1 class="title">Right Menu</h1>
          </ion-header-bar>
          <ion-content>
            <ul class="list">
              <li>
                <a class="item" menu-close nav-clear href="#/search">Search</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a class="item" menu-close nav-clear href="#/settings">Settings</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu>

      </ion-side-menus>



    <script id="tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">

        <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/home">
          <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="About" icon="ion-ios7-information" href="#/tab/about">
          <ion-nav-view name="about-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="Contact" icon="ion-ios7-world" ui-sref="tabs.contact">
          <ion-nav-view name="contact-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

      </ion-tabs>
    </script>

    <script id="home.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view title="Home">
        <ion-content>
          <p>Example of Ionic tabs. Navigate to each tab, and
          navigate to child views of each tab and notice how
          each tab has its own navigation history.</p>
          <p>
            <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/facts">Scientific Facts</a>
          </p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="facts.html" type="text/ng-template">

      <ion-view title="Facts">
        <ion-content>
          <p>Banging your head against a wall uses 150 calories an hour.</p>
          <p>Dogs have four toes on their hind feet, and five on their front feet.</p>
          <p>The ant can lift 50 times its own weight, can pull 30 times its own weight and always falls over on its right side when intoxicated.</p>
          <p>A cockroach will live nine days without it's head, before it starves to death.</p>
          <p>Polar bears are left handed.</p>
          <p>
            <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
            <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/facts2">More Facts</a>
          </p>

        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="facts2.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view title="Also Factual">
        <ion-content>
          <p>111,111,111 x 111,111,111 = 12,345,678,987,654,321</p>
          <p>1 in every 4 Americans has appeared on T.V.</p>
          <p>11% of the world is left-handed.</p>
          <p>1 in 8 Americans has worked at a McDonalds restaurant.</p>
          <p>$283,200 is the absolute highest amount of money you can win on Jeopardy.</p>
          <p>101 Dalmatians, Peter Pan, Lady and the Tramp, and Mulan are the only Disney cartoons where both parents are present and don't die throughout the movie.</p>
          <p>
            <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
            <a class="button icon ion-chevron-left" href="#/tab/facts"> Scientific Facts</a>
          </p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="about.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view title="About">
        <ion-content>
          <h3>Create hybrid mobile apps with the web technologies you love.</h3>
          <p>Free and open source, Ionic offers a library of mobile-optimized HTML, CSS and JS components for building highly interactive apps.</p>
          <p>Built with Sass and optimized for AngularJS.</p>
          <p>
            <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/navstack">Tabs Nav Stack</a>
          </p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="nav-stack.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view title="Tab Nav Stack">
        <ion-content>
          <p><img src="http://ionicframework.com/img/diagrams/tabs-nav-stack.png" style="width:100%"></p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="contact.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view title="Contact">
        <ion-content>
          <p>@IonicFramework</p>
          <p>@DriftyCo</p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="settings.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view title="Settings">
        <ion-content>
          Settings page
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="search.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view title="Search">
        <ion-content>
          Search page
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

  </body>
</html>


angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('search', {
      url: '/search',
      templateUrl: 'search.html'
    })
    .state('settings', {
      url: '/settings',
      templateUrl: 'settings.html'
    })
    .state('tabs', {
      url: "/tab",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "tabs.html"
    })
    .state('tabs.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "home.html",
          controller: 'HomeTabCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.facts', {
      url: "/facts",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "facts.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.facts2', {
      url: "/facts2",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "facts2.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.about', {
      url: "/about",
      views: {
        'about-tab': {
          templateUrl: "about.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.navstack', {
      url: "/navstack",
      views: {
        'about-tab': {
          templateUrl: "nav-stack.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.contact', {
      url: "/contact",
      views: {
        'contact-tab': {
          templateUrl: "contact.html"
        }
      }
    });


   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab/home");

})
.controller('NavCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
  $scope.showMenu = function () {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
  };
  $scope.showRightMenu = function () {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleRight();
  };
})
.controller('HomeTabCtrl', function($scope) {
});
```

Comment: its running in web browser but not in mobile native app